# Spectrum of $(A^TA-B^TB)$ and $(AA^T-BB^T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am wondering whether one can say anything useful about the relationship of $A^TA-B^TB$ and $AA^T-BB^T$ in terms of their spectra?

In particular I know that their traces are the same since $tr(A^TA-B^TB) = tr(A^TA)-tr(B^TB) = tr(AA^T)-tr(BB^T) = tr(AA^T-BB^T)$. But I am wondering what can be said about the relationship in terms of their Frobenius norm, spectral norm, or lower order eigenvalues?

Specifically, is it true that $\|A^TA-B^TB\|_F=\|AA^T-BB^T\|_F$, $\|A^TA-B^TB\|_2=\|AA^T-BB^T\|_2$, or even $\forall i: \lambda_i(A^TA-B^TB)=\lambda_i(AA^T-BB^T)$, where $\lambda_i(\cdot)$ denotes the $i$-th eigenvalue?

Comment: In general, it is not true that $|A^TA-B^TB|_F = |AA^T-BB^T|_F$, $|A^TA-B^TB|_2 = |AA^T-BB^T|_2$, or $\forall i: \lambda_i(A^TA-B^TB) = \lambda_i(AA^T-BB^T)$. The relationship between the eigenvalues and norms of these expressions is more complex and not directly linked in such a simple manner.

Comment: Counterexample: Let A and B as two column vectors that have unit norm and are orthogonal to each other (the latter is not important; they just need to have an angle with each other). Then A^T A - B^T B = 0, but AA^T - BB^T clearly is non-zero.